# WPF ListBox Binding yields one character per line

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to pound data binding and wpf into my (apparently thick) head.  I have a very simple program where I have an ObservableCollection of objects that contain a single property -- a string.  When I run it, it presents the listbox as one character per line, and only of the first item.

This must be simple, but I'm stumped.  If I remove the 'binding.Path = ...", then it will display "expOne.FNode" on each line (thrice).

Thank you!

Code below:
MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace expOne
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<FNode> MyFileList = new ObservableCollection<FNode>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        MyFileList.Add ( new FNode ( "alpha" ) );
        MyFileList.Add ( new FNode ( "bravo" ) );
        MyFileList.Add ( new FNode ( "charlie" ) );
        InitializeComponent();
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = MyFileList;
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath ( "Name" );
        mylistbox.SetBinding ( ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding );
    }
}
}
```

FNode.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace expOne
{
public class FNode
{
    private string m_name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return ( m_name ); }
        set { m_name = value; }
    }

    public FNode ( string n )
    {
        m_name = n;
    }

    public FNode()
    {
        m_name = "Bob";
    }
}
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="expOne.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="mylistbox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="15" >
            <!--<ListBoxItem Content="First or Last" />-->
        </ListBox> 
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to set path on binding, just set Source for your binding. Remove this:

```
binding.Path = new PropertyPath ( "Name" );
```

OR

Simply omit the binding and directly set ItemsSource on listBox:

```
MyFileList.Add(new FNode("alpha"));
MyFileList.Add(new FNode("bravo"));
MyFileList.Add(new FNode("charlie"));
InitializeComponent();
mylistbox.ItemsSource = MyFileList;
```

and set `DisplayMemberPath` on ListBox to `Name` otherwise it will call `ToString()` on your class FNode and will print fully qualified name of your class that's why you seeing `expOne.FNode` to be print thrice.

```
<ListBox Name="mylistbox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         FontSize="15" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Comment: Thanks!  (to both of you).  How is 'DisplayMemberPath' different from 'binding.Path'?  When is the binding.Path used?

Comment: `Path` is property on Binding class where `DisplayMemberPath` is a property of `ItemsControl`. When you specify path you are actually telling binding engine to set ItemsSource to that path in binding. Whereas with `DisplayMemberPath` you tell to bind property in underlying ItemSource.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you bound the 'Name' property to the ItemsSource of you Listbox, essentially telling the listbox to bind to the characters in the string. The listbox binds to the combination of the Source and Path properties.

To bind the Listbox to the list, just set the source. To display the Name, set the ListBox's [DisplayMemberPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to "Name"

Actually, it's much easier to bind declaratively. You can set the list as the DataContext of the Listbox  eg.

```
ObservableCollection<FNode> MyFileList = new ObservableCollection<FNode>();
public MainWindow()
{
    MyFileList.Add ( new FNode ( "alpha" ) );
    MyFileList.Add ( new FNode ( "bravo" ) );
    MyFileList.Add ( new FNode ( "charlie" ) );
    InitializeComponent();
    mylistbox.DataContext=MyFileList;
}
```

and then set the binding in XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="mylistbox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Data binding allows to you to completely separate the data from your window. In fact, the MVVM style prescribes that your presentation data (the ViewModel) should be a separate class from your window (your View). This way you can bind different data classes to the same view, or different views to the same object.

Assuming you created a class named `MyProjectViewModel` with `Name` and `Files` properties, you could write this:

```
public MyProjectViewModel TheProject {get;set;}
public MainWindow()
{
    TheProject=new MyProject();

    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext=TheProject;
}
```

and then bind any elements you need to this ViewModel's properties, eg:

```
<TextBox Name="projectName" Text="{Binding Name}" />
<ListBox Name="projectFiles" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" 
                             DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Comment: If I omit the  binding.Path = new PropertyPath ( "Name" ); statement, then the list box contains three lines of "expOne.FNode"  which is the namespace + type name...

Comment: Did you add "DisplayMemberPath" ?

Comment: uh, no... To what do I set it?  Sorry to be sooo dense.